# Need a way to limit the time available to actually take a quiz built with PHP to 50 minutes

Tags: php, forms, timer

I have this basic code for a quiz of 60 questions. What I need is a way to limit the quiz taker to 50 minutes to take the quiz, after which the form automatically calls the next file. Cream on top would be to have the available time displayed on the page. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php
// Start output buffering.
ob_start();
// Initialize a session.
session_start();
echo '<form action="sampleform.php" onSubmit="return verify()" method="post">';
echo '<p>1. Question</p><ul><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" />&nbsp;<b>A.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Answer1</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" />&nbsp;<b>B.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Answer2</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="C" />&nbsp;<b>C.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Answer3</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="D" />&nbsp;<b>D.&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>Answer4</li><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="?" checked style="display:none;" /></li></ul>';
// Total of 60 questions.
echo '<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click ONCE when finished." /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /></form>';
<?php // Flush the buffered output.
ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: The only way to enforce this constraint using PHP only is to have the server remember the time of serving the quiz file, and invalidating the submitted form data if its respective time has passed.

Doing this "automatically" requires the form (frontend) to communicate with the backend (PHP) asynchronously. Which is very interesting, but makes things much more complicated. More so than justifying answering your question.

Comment: Invalidating the form will not work, as the responses collected in it need to be forwarded to the next file. Might there be another way via JS or something else? I'm trying to determine if this is even feasible.

Comment: Yes, there is a way with JS.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you mentioned js in the comments, so here is an answer for your question but in js (I don't do PHP)

There is a concept called Dates in js, which can be used to calculate time.

```
new Date()
```

represents the date the moment the code is run.

You can find the difference between 2 dates.

There is another concept called intervals.
You can set a piece of code to run at an interval.
Combining the two concepts together,

```
let start = new Date() // runs at the start of the test
let interval = setInterval(function(){
//code to run
let now = new Date()
if((Math.abs(start-now)/1000)>=50){
//find difference between times and divide by 1000 to get it in minuits, then compare it to 50

stopInterval(interval) // stops the interval from running
console.log('TIME REACHED')
//do what you need to do here; the time is up

}

}, 1000) // records the fingerprint so we can stop the interval later (Code runs every second or 1000 milliseconds)
```